# How to connect a tab to vertical scrollbar?

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to associate a vertical scrollbar to the tab in tabwidget. Did someone know any example or anything?. 
Here is the code:

```
self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self.frame)
    self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 140, 542, 465))#260,140,431,391
    self.tabWidget.setTabShape(QtGui.QTabWidget.Rounded)
    self.tabWidget.setUsesScrollButtons(True)
    self.tabWidget.setDocumentMode(False)
    self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(False)
    self.tabWidget.setMovable(False)
    self.tabWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tabWidget"))
    self.tab = QtGui.QWidget()
    self.tab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab"))


    self.verticalScrollBar = QtGui.QScrollBar(self.tab)
    self.verticalScrollBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(522, 0, 15, 432))#490,0,16,351
    self.verticalScrollBar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
    self.verticalScrollBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalScrollBar"))
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Do you have a screenshot of some similary application with such widget? Do you want to have a scrollable tab page?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the vertical scrollbar is outside of tab Widget, find a signal you want then connect it to a slot function of the tab.